# Undefined symbols during compile/load in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, subclass

I'm doing a storyboard tutorial (Beginning iOS Storyboarding) and one of the sample programs won't compile.  I've had this issue before with object classes not being recognized by the compiler but I can't find the problem.

What am I missing?

Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o

```
MainViewController.m
--------------------
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
{

}
@end

@implementation MainViewController

@end

MainViewController.h
--------------------

#import "FlipsideViewController.h"

#import "AudioPlayer.h"
#import "PlayButton.h"
#import "Scale.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
<FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,
AudioPlayerDelegate,
PlayButtonDelegate,
UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

@end

AudioPlayer.m
-------------
#import "AudioPlayer.h"
@interface AudioPlayer () {

}

...(snip)...

@end

@implementation AudioPlayer

...(snip)...
@end

AudioPlayer.h
-------------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

...(snip)...

@protocol AudioPlayerDelegate;

@interface AudioPlayer : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

}

...(snip)...

@end

@protocol AudioPlayerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)player:(AudioPlayer *)player stateChanged:(ePlayerState)state;
@end
```

Comment: are you adding the  #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> and the AudioToolbox framework?

Comment: Probably `AudioPlayer.m` is not compiled for your target. Select the file on the Navigator and make sure your target is selected in Target Membership section of the File Inspector.

Comment: That was it - had to add all the class files to the Compile under Build Phases.

Frameworks were properly included - I should have said that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing symbols are because when you use a framework that isn't one of the ones automatically added to the project, you need to tell the compiler add them to it's list of places to look.

To do this, open the left hand panel (apple 1), and select the project's active target.  You're looking for something like build steps, and the fourth one down will be link frameworks.  Open that up and search for your missing framework.  Generally, it has the same name as the first part of the include, so it is probably AudioToolbox.framework.

Answer (score 0):

Murat's comment fixed this issue.   But in Xcode doesn't automatically add .m files to be compiled when you copy them and don't modify them.

Probably AudioPlayer.m is not compiled for your target. Select the file on the Navigator and make sure your target is selected in Target Membership section of the File Inspector. – murat Apr 28 at 15:25